# How can I json_encode the output of my function?

Tags: functions, ajax, json

How can I json_encode the output of this function I use to get all attached images of a post?

```
<?php
function get_all_images($postid=0, $size='bigger', $attributes='') {
    if ($postid<1) $postid = get_the_ID();
    if ($images = get_children(array(
        'post_parent' => $postid,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $attachment=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);
            ?><img src="<?php echo $attachment[0]; ?>" alt="" /><?php
        }
}?>
```

Everything is already setup for admin-ajax.php.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing with it on the front-end. Are you iterating through them via JS or just dumping a block of HTML?

Comment: Probably should stick to your original duplicate posting: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62466/getting-all-the-attached-images-of-a-post-via-ajax-json

Comment: I'm using it as a block of HTML but I guess it would be better to iterate through jQuery?

Comment: Why did you delete the original question that was already a duplicate and now asking the same thing again?

Comment: The first question was not as well explained. The proof is that I got an answer for this one not the previous one.

Comment: @Gab You got an edit button for your questions. Making an edit brings it back to page 1. Please use this one the next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the `get_all_images()` function is the one that is added to your wp_ajax_{action} hook.  If it is you will want to output a string back to your js.  I would define a variable and concatenate the img html to it as you loop through your images.

```
function get_all_images() {
//your code
$response = '';
foreach($images as $image) {
        $attachment=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);

        $response .= '<img src="'.$attachment[0].'" alt="" />';
    }

 die( json_encode( $response ) );

}
```